# Get text selection colour and background colour in current browser

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

When I select some text in browser with mouse, it appears white with blue background.

I would like to simulate text selection by means element's style. How can I get those default colors in javascript code ?

Comment: Did you try `style` for element i.e `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: yes, but the questions is how to get this color? In mozilla this is lightbule, in chrome this is blue with a bit of transparency.

Answer (score -2):

This should help.

https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Also you can use window.getSelection() API to play with javascript.

Comment: Saw it. The question is how to get default color and background color?